# how to get package coverage in R even if few tests fail

Tags: r, code-coverage

When running `package_coverage()`, if the test fail the execution is halting and not returning any partial coverage

I tried

```
cov <- package_coverage(path=".", type="tests", x<-test_dir("tests/"))
cov <- package_coverage(path=".", type="tests")
```

Comment: Surely `x<-test_dir="tests/"` is a typo? Also, while this isn't responsive to your question, my suggestion is honestly to worry much more about failing tests than coverage. You need good coverage, but what does it matter if you're failing the tests you do have?

Comment: I corrected the typo . I am loosing the coverage even if all tests except the last test pass. I am just looking for option that if we could get the intermediate coverage till then